# How can I launch Java tests using Perl?

Tags: java, perl, launch, testing

How can I launch a Java test suite using Perl?

Comment: Why are you using perl for this?

Comment: Perl is great for process management - its dated for stuff like this, but still...

Comment: Perl offers a variety of tools for working with child processes.  Which one to use depends on how you want to interact with the test scripts.  Do you want to capture your test's STDOUT and/or STDERR? Do you need to automate interaction with your script through STDIN/STDOUT? Do you want your Perl script to block while the test runs or should it continue?

Comment: @Sinan, I think it's supposed to be *campaign*.  Which I guess means a test suite.  If so, its particularly important to know if the test output needs to be collected or processed and if multiple tests should be run at once.  This seems like it could be a good opportunity to use Perl's test frameworks.  But since laura won't elaborate on her question its kind of a moot point.

Comment: @daotoad That makes sense. I wanted to edit the question because it did seem interesting: After all, there are a lot of ways to make testing more tolerable using Perl ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**system function**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

```
system("java Sample");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [JMX](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl-0.51/lib/JMX/Jmx4Perl.pm) module if possible.

Comment: not necessary perl in this case, but overall developers use perl to launch may java tests , the issue that I need to clarify is how to call all java tests to launch them using script perl or any other language

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) or [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) to issue the relevant `java ...` command line, e.g.:

```
system('java ClassName some arguments here');
```